# fft fixpoint using Intel IPP

Tags: fft, intel-ipp

I am new in IPP Intel. I have downloaded the l_ipp_2017.0.098 and installed it but I do not see the API for FFT fix point (ippsFFTFwd_CToC_16sc_Sfs) under the include dir

Answer (score 1):

This function was deprecated in IPP 9.0 and got moved to [IPP 9.0 Legacy library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp-legacy-libraries). It can be obtained from this library, but will lack optimization for the latest CPU architectures.